# train logistic regression model with different feature dimension in scikit learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Using Python 2.7 on Windows. Want to fit a logistic regression model using feature `T1` and `T2` for a classification problem, and target is `T3`.

I show the values of `T1` and `T2`, as well as my code. The question is, since `T1` has dimension 5, and `T2` has dimension 1, how should we pre-process them so that it could be leveraged by scikit-learn logistic regression training correctly?

BTW, I mean for training sample 1, its feature of `T1` is `[ 0 -1 -2 -3]`, and feature of `T2` is `[0]`, for training sample 2, its feature of T1 is `[ 1  0 -1 -2]` and feature of `T2` is `[1]`, ...

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets

arc = lambda r,c: r-c
T1 = np.array([[arc(r,c) for c in xrange(4)] for r in xrange(5)])
print T1
print type(T1)
T2 = np.array([[arc(r,c) for c in xrange(1)] for r in xrange(5)])
print T2
print type(T2)
T3 = np.array([0,0,1,1,1])

logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)

# we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
# using T1 and T2 as features, and T3 as target
logreg.fit(T1+T2, T3)
```

T1,

```
[[ 0 -1 -2 -3]
 [ 1  0 -1 -2]
 [ 2  1  0 -1]
 [ 3  2  1  0]
 [ 4  3  2  1]]
```

T2,

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to concatenate the feature data matrices using numpy.concatenate.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets

arc = lambda r,c: r-c
T1 = np.array([[arc(r,c) for c in xrange(4)] for r in xrange(5)])
T2 = np.array([[arc(r,c) for c in xrange(1)] for r in xrange(5)])
T3 = np.array([0,0,1,1,1])

X = np.concatenate((T1,T2), axis=1)
Y = T3
logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)

# we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
# using T1 and T2 as features, and T3 as target
logreg.fit(X, Y)

X_test = np.array([[1, 0, -1, -1, 1],
                   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,]])

print logreg.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thanks Daewon, vote up. After concatenate, will logistic regression think there are 6 features per training sample?

Comment: BTW, what is the purpose of `X_test`?

Comment: @LinMa Yes, you are right. After concatenating, you have 6 features (the first five features from T1 and the last one from T2). X_test is appended by myself just for testing :)

Comment: Thanks Daewon, wondering if there is any benefit to keep them separate features (but with different dimension, one feature is a 4 dimension vector, the other one is a scalar), and still leverage logistic regression to do training?

Comment: @LinMa I don't know the advantages of maintaining separate features, because the intention of this analysis is not given. Anyway, you should merge features to use sklearn's `LogisticRegression`. But, you still maintain your features separately in different variables (You just merge them temporarily for analysis).

Comment: Thanks for the help Daewon, mark your reply as answer.